# Blank Local Variable Declaration - JS

Tags: javascript, function, variables, scope

I have exactly the same code below except the top is from the HeadFirst JS book where they declare output as a blank variable then assign it a string. Second is me messing around and seeing the code still works without first declaring output as a blank variable. What's the use for declaring output; blank vs just skipping that part.

```
const printAndGetHighScore = function (score) {
    let highscore = 0;
    let output;
    for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        output = `Bubble solution #${i} score: ${scores[i]}`;
        console.log(output);
        if (scores[i] > highscore){
            highscore = scores[i]
        }
    }
    return highscore;
};
const printAndGetHighScore = function (scores) {
    let highscore = 0
    for (let i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        let output = `Bubble Solution #${i} score: ${scores[i]}`
        if(scores[i] > highscore){
            highscore = scores[i]
        }
    }
    return highscore;
}
console.log(`Bubbles test: ${scores.length}`);
console.log(`Highest bubble score ${printAndGetHighScore(scores)}`)
```

Comment: Should the second example have a `console.log(output);` in it, just like the first has?

Comment: Your first loop is missing the `let i` declaration

Answer (score 0):

In this case, there is no difference. Since `output` is only referenced once, and it's done synchronously inside the loop right after `output` gets assigned to, it doesn't matter where the variable is declared - from the perspective of getting the code working.

One could have even declared `output` outside, or `highscore` outside:

```
let output;
let highscore;
const printAndGetHighScore = function (score) {
    highscore = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < scores.length; i++) {
        output = `Bubble solution #${i} score: ${scores[i]}`;
        console.log(output);
        if (scores[i] > highscore){
            highscore = scores[i]
        }
    }
    return highscore;
};
```

This would work too.

A situation where declaring variables outside a loop instead of inside a loop wouldn't work would be if the variables were referencable *later*, such as in functions:

```js
const fns = [];
let i = 0;
for (; i < 3; i++) {
  fns.push(() => console.log(i));
}
for (const fn of fns) fn();
```

In the above example, since there's only one binding for `i` created, the created functions all reference that single `i`, which is 3 after the loop finishes. Declaring a variable inside the loop would allow all functions to have separate bindings:

```js
const fns = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  const inner = i; // not strictly necesary, but makes the scoping easier to understand
  fns.push(() => console.log(inner));
}
for (const fn of fns) fn();
```

But there's another reason to prefer declaring variables inside a loop (like your second example) instead of outside: **code maintainability**. [The narrower a scope a variable has, the easier it is to reason about it and the code around it.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/388052/rationale-to-prefer-local-variables-over-instance-variables)

Comment: When an answer solves your problem, you can consider marking it as Accepted (check the checkmark on the left) to indicate the issue is resolved :)